# Would this be a good reason for child domains?

Tags: active-directory

I am building out a sharepoint environment, which would have dev/prod domains. However, I will also be hosting a number of infrastructure servers in the network such as WSUS, DHCP, WDS, etc.

I am thinking that I can create two child domains under a parent domain called say INFRASTRUCTURE, which comprise of the respective dev and prod sharepoint environments.

Is there any flaw in this design? It's either this or 3 seperate flat domains under the forest.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need multiple domains? Why can't DEV and PROD live in the same AD domain?

Comment: To add to @joeqwerty's point, I think you are approaching the question as a web developer.  An active directory domain is not a physical representation of a specific set of resources as opposed to a website/app domain which is a physical end-point.  An AD domain is a collection of data, resources, and clients.  You may want to pick up one of William Stanek's books on Windows Server and read the sections of Active Directory, it is often very helpful in understanding how things should be broken out.

Answer (score 5):

Domains in the same forest are management boundaries. Separate forests are security boundaries.

If your concern is management, use separate domains (child or disjoint doesn't matter much). If your concern is security, use separate forests with a trust if necessary. If your concern is neither, you probably don't need a separate domain. We can't answer this for you.